# How do I paste from the clipboard into Emacs in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, emacs

I am using GNU Emacs (latest version) on Windows XP. How do I paste content from the Windows clipboard into Emacs?

Comment: Just a tip: "latest version" does not say much in say six months time. Furthermore it is unclear since there might be stable/unstable/beta/snapshot/etc. versions available - which is the latest? Always specify _which_ version you mean. It will help you get better answers to your questions in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Using mouse middle button works for me.